# codigo can bus, no consigo que me verifique. PROYECTO clase

Tags: c++, arduino, modbus

antes de nada, decir que estoy en un grado de electricidad, y me han pedido un proyecto con la red CAN, no tenemos conocimientos de programación y tenemos un código, que va a funcionar con dos placas UNO de Arduino, dos controladores y van ha hacer un la función de  transmisor y otra de receptor.
El código que me falla es el del transmisor.
Le he echo alguna modificación respecto al que nos dan, que viene de este link (https://www.electronicshub.org/arduino-mcp2515-can-bus-tutorial/)
Y este es mi código con la modificación

```
  #include <SPI.h>
#include <mcp_can.h>

const int spiCSPin = 10;
int ledHIGH    = 1;
int ledLOW     = 0;
int CAN;

const int SPI_CS_PIN =9;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    while (CAN_OK != CAN.begin (CAN_500KBPS))
    {
        Serial.println("CAN BUS init Failed");
        delay(100);
    }
    Serial.println("CAN BUS Shield Init OK!");
}

unsigned char stmp[8] = {ledHIGH, 1, 2, 3, ledLOW, 5, 6, 7};
    
void loop()
{   
  Serial.println("In loop");
  CAN.sendMsgBuf (0x43, 0, 8, stmp);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

Haz copiado mal el código. Donde dice

```
const int spiCSPin = 10;
int ledHIGH    = 1;
int ledLOW     = 0;

MCP_CAN CAN(spiCSPin);
```

tú escribiste

```
const int spiCSPin = 10;
int ledHIGH    = 1;
int ledLOW     = 0;
int CAN;
```

con lo que desapareció el objeto CAN, siendo reemplazado por un entero del mismo nombre, sin inicializar, para peor.

Comment: si lo modifico, me sale el siguiente error: request for member 'begin' in 'CAN', which is of non-class type 'int'

Comment: @RastaGainCOD. Sospecho que `mcp_can.h` proviene de una librería distinta a la que usa la página original (https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Seeed_Arduino_CAN/tree/master/src). Revise los fuentes y ejemplos y se ve que CAN es un objeto, no un entero, lo que sustenta la tesis.